# Referencing Object Id not working in Mongoose 4.11.6

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this problem. Basically, I have 2 schemas - a User schema and a Document schema. The Document schema has an `owner` which references the `_id` field of documents in the `User` collection.

The problem is that I am still able to save documents in the `Document` collection with owner ids that do not exist in the `User` collection which should not be so.

Here is my `User` schema and `Document` schema respectively

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
 email: {
   type: String,
   validate: [{ validator: value => isEmail(value), msg: 'Invalid email.' 
  }],
  unique: true,
  required: true,
},
password: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
},
isAdmin: {
  type: Boolean,
  default: false,
 },
}, {
timestamps: true,
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

And the Document Schema

```
const DocumentSchema = new Schema({
   title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
   },
   text: {
     type: String,
   },
  access: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['public', 'private'],
    default: 'public',
  },
 owner: {
   type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: 'User',
   required: true,
  },
 }, {
 timestamps: true,
});

const Document = mongoose.model('Document', DocumentSchema);
```

Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Mongodb doesn't provide data consistency. Use RDBMS, if you need this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that situation you can add `pre save` function in your `Document` schema that will call before `save` your `Document`.

```
const DocumentSchema = new Schema({
  // ...
 }, {
 timestamps: true,
});


DocumentSchema .pre("save",function(next) {
  var self = this;
  if (self.owner) {
    mongoose.models['User'].findOne({_id : self.owner }, function(err, existUser){
      if(err){
        return next(false, err);
      }

      if(!existUser)
        return next(false, "Invalid user reference");
      else
        return next(true);
    });
  } else {
    next(false, "Owner is required");
  }
});

const Document = mongoose.model('Document', DocumentSchema);
```